# QOpenGLShader Can't Compile GLSL 120 On Android

Tags: qt, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I have programed OpenGL code on Qt5 for Mac OS 10.10. The GLSL version is 120 and there is no problem to run.

```
#version 120
attribute highp vec4 vVertex;
attribute vec3 vNormal;

uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
uniform mat4 mvMatrix;
uniform mat4 normalMatrix;
uniform vec3 vLightPosition;

varying vec3 vVaryingNormal;
varying vec3 vVaryingLightDir;

void main(void)
{
    vVaryingNormal = mat3(normalMatrix) * vNormal;
    vec4 vPosition4 = mvMatrix * vVertex;
    vec3 vPosition3 = vPosition4.xyz / vPosition4.w;

    vVaryingLightDir = normalize(vLightPosition-vPosition3);
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vVertex;
}
```

When I tried to move the code to compile and run for Andriod, I get the flowwing error:

```
W/Qt      (21457): (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShader::compile(Vertex): 0:1:
P0007: Language version '120' unknown, this compiler only supports  up to
version '300 es'
```

Why QOpenGLShader for Andriod can't support glsl 120? How to solve the problem?

Comment: Because Android supports OpenGL ES, not full OpenGL. `120` is not a valid GLSL version for ES. You'll want to use either `100 es` (for ES 2.0) or `300 es` (for ES 3.0).

Comment: use "#version 100 es" instead of "#version 120"?

Comment: @RetoKoradi - this is an actual answer to question.

Comment: @keaukraine Yes, it sort of was. I wasn't sure if there was enough substance in this question for a real answer. I added one now.

Comment: but Android 4.3+ should support opengl 30, why is there a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android uses OpenGL ES, and GLSL versions are different between OpenGL ES and full OpenGL.

Valid versions for OpenGL ES are:

- `version 100`: ES 2.0.
- `version 300 es`: ES 3.0.
- `version 310 es`: ES 3.1.

Valid versions for full OpenGL are:

- `version 110`: OpenGL 2.0.
- `version 120`: OpenGL 2.1.
- `version 130`: OpenGL 3.0.
- `version 140`: OpenGL 3.1.
- `version 150`: OpenGL 3.2.
- `version 330`: OpenGL 3.3.
- `version 400`: OpenGL 4.0.
- `version 410`: OpenGL 4.1.
- `version 420`: OpenGL 4.2.
- `version 430`: OpenGL 4.3.
- `version 440`: OpenGL 4.4.
- `version 450`: OpenGL 4.5.

Starting with OpenGL 3.2 (`version 150`), an optional profile can be specified. Valid version strings for 3.3 are for example:

```
#version 330
#version 330 core
#version 330 compatibility
```

In your case, you will probably want to use the lowest ES version that supports the feature set you need. If ES 2.0 is enough, you would use:

```
#version 100
```

and if you need ES 3.0:

```
#version 300 es
```

You can also use the predefined `GL_ES` preprocessor symbol to make the version conditional, and use the same shader code for OpenGL ES and OpenGL:

```
#if GL_ES
#version 300 es
#else
#version 120
#endif
```

Comment: but Android 4.3+ should support opengl 30, why is there a bug?